# Postgres select non regex query

Tags: sql, postgresql

We would like to do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE char_length(text) >= 15 AND char_length(text) <= 100
```

HOWEVER, we want it to return only 'text' column that matches this query WITHOUT hashtags. that is:
If `text = 'hello how are you'` will match
but
`text = 'hello #how #are you'` will not match (because we want to filter out the hashtags and `char_length('hello you')` is too short).

Comment: I might have misunderstood you but why don't you just add: and text not like '%#%'

Comment: I want to do char_length excluding the hashtags

Comment: @OleEHDufour Close...but `#` could be in the middle of a string and not be part of a hashtag.  Your suggested `LIKE` expression would fail _all_ pound signs.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort, and there's not even a list of unambiguous sample inputs/outputs.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well, your answer isn't useful because it doesn't answer OP's (clarified) question. Am I supposed to not downvote bad answers for fear of revenge?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove hashtags from the text and check that the remaining string is within your desired length bounds:

```
with t as (select 'this is some text' as txt union all 
           select 'this is #hashed text - loong' union all 
           select 'too short #despite #many #hashtags')
select * from t
where length(regexp_replace(txt, '#[a-z]+ *', '', 'g')) between 15 and 100
```

You might want to fiddle a bit with the regexp `#[a-z]+ *` recognizing your tags. Note that the `'g'` makes `regexp_replace` replace *all* occurrences of the regexp, not just the first one, see [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html).

Comment: Nice approach, but be careful that your pattern does not also remove `#` when it be not associated with a hashtag.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a POSIX regex which does *not* match the pattern `.*([ ]|^)#[a-z].*`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    char_length(text) >= 15 AND
    char_length(text) <= 100 AND
    text !~* '.*([ ]|^)#[a-z].*';
```

### Demo

Comment: I want to do char_length excluding the hashtags

Comment: @Himberjack :  the `Where text !~*`  is already excluding the hashtags, what do you mean by "do char_length excluding the hashtags"

Comment: @Himberjack Check the demo I added.  If it fails for some edge cases you have in mind, I can edit my answer.

Comment: Your code rejects `'hello how are you #yolo'`, which OP presumably wants to be included.